# How do I get PHP to kill www-data processes?

Tags: php, python, linux, bash

I have a Debian server running apache2/PHP. From this website I can execute many python scripts over time. I want to be able to kill these scripts after a certain amount of time so that they don't pile up. The python scripts are owned by www-data.

I have tried killing the python scripts by storing the PID and the time stamp of execution and then looping through all these to find the ones older than a given time.

```
for($x = 0; $x < $arraylen; $x++) {
    if ( round(microtime(true)) - $timearray[$x] > 60){
        $command = "kill -9 " .  $pidarray[$x];
        $killme = exec($command);
    }
}
```

I grab the PID using this:

```
$PID = shell_exec('/usr/bin/python2.7 /var/www/worker.py ......');
```

I cannot seem to get PHP to kill these processes. However, if I know the PID of the process I can type this into the terminal which works fine

```
sudo su www-data
kill "PID of the process"
```

How do I get PHP to kill one of its own processes?

Comment: The user www-data most likely does not have the rights to kill another process, even if it is its own child. But I think would rather use a cron-job than a web-process to kill hung processes, so you can execute them as root if you have access to that. I'd additionally recommend to talk to the linux-/unix-speficic SE's around here.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec("sudo -u <YOURUSER> -S kill $PID");
```

Comment: is that $PID supposed to be inside the "" and not at the end with a  . $PID

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!